# Discussion-based questions

Tags: discussion

I ran into an issue today with a question of mine where I was interested in the advantages and disadvantages of doing something a certain way. While eventually I was convinced that StackOverflow and the broader StackExchange are not good places for discussion based questions, I was interested in ways to restructure the question to make it seem like something of a discussion while living up to the merits of a Q&A site. What is the best way to handle reforming such a question?

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305626/serializing-objects-to-xml-im-not-asking-how-to-do-it) (post-edit). The background was originally a part 1.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124930/165773

Answer (score 3):

Discussion based questions are inherently off-topic for SO, because of their *unanswerable nature* and being *opinion based*. See the related close reason's text:

> "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

As from your sample's text:

> *"what will be the simplest for a low- to mid-level experienced programmer and the most well-structured in terms of class design?"*

This would need to exactly specify who are *low-*, *mid-* and *experienced-* level programmers in 1st place, to get non opinion based answers for the question.

Comment: The issue is that the advantages and disadvantages of object serialization are not opinion based; there are quantifiable ways to measure them

Comment: @BenKnoble See my edit. Also listing advantages and disadvantages of different techniques might come out to be _too broad_, which is off topic as well.

Comment: Again; that is not the primary issue here. This was after I tried to restructure the question to make it more suitable. I am referring to discussing the advantages and disadvantages of object serialization.

Comment: @BenKnoble how do you [select the right answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) from a discussion question?

Comment: Fair point @MichaelT. Potentially the one that does the best job of explaining the adv and disadv?

Comment: @BenKnoble I find it surprising you read that full blog post in under a minute.  I would urge you to read it carefully.

Comment: Oh i didnt read it @MichaelT i merely answered the question

Comment: @BenKnoble I'd also suggest adding [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/40980) from Meta.Programmers.SE to your reading list.

Comment: The second post makes a valid counter argument. However i think the first reaffirms my point: im looking for an explanation of the advs and disadvs.

Comment: @BenKnoble You missed the point of Real Questions Have Answers - "real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions." - asking for the pros and cons of a particular design choice are not answers. They are items on a list. Opinions on what is valuable and what is not. They are not answers. It emphasizes "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" - pros and cons is not that.  "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page" - a pros and cons list is *exactly* open ended.

Comment: Again @MichaelT Im forces to acknowledge the validity of the point. I think the discussion has moved away from the question: how do you reform a question to still work?

Comment: @BenKnoble quite simply sit down and ask "what problem am I trying to solve? What have I already done to attempt to solve this that was not successful? Why were these attempts not successful? What outcome do I want?" - base the question on answering those four questions and you should have something that is either answerable itself, or able to be modified to be answerable in a productive manner in the Q&A format that Stack Overflow uses.

Comment: @MichaelT have you seen the SE question best way to calculate pi? It answers these 4 questions obviously, but it also is structured in a way that provokes some kind of "what is valuable" sort of answers.